# What determines whether or not a question is tweeted?

Tags: discussion

Out of sheer curiosity, I am wondering about the WordPress Answers Twitter account.  What determines whether a question gets tweeted or not?  I see that a tweet goes out roughly once every three hours.  I thought maybe it tweets highly rated questions without answers, or maybe questions with a lot of activity, but [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/111246/32110), with a score of only 1, was [tweeted](https://twitter.com/StackWordPress/status/370745439202840577) 8 hours after the answer (also a score of 1) was accepted.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101340/145551

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Jeff Atwood explained in [one of his answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101340/232449) generally how the Twitter accounts work.  There is some discussion in that question (from 2 years ago) on adding a manual, human component to the accounts.  Did that ever happen, or is the WordPress Answers Twitter account still entirely automated?

Comment: @Ben Miller: For the moment all official Twitter feeds are automated.  (However, some individuals [on other sites](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/956/what-is-the-difference-between-twitter-accounts) have set up their own Twitter accounts, which broadcast interesting questions manually.)